The existence of solutions to linear systems of equations over the integer ring $\mathbb{Z}$
There are already detailed results on the solutions of linear equations over fields, but I'd like to inquire about any good conclusions regarding the solutions of linear equations over the integer ring $\mathbb{Z}$. Specifically, the issue arises from the first equation in the image.
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{21} & \cdots & a_{m 1} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{m 2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{1 n} & a_{2 n} & \cdots & a_{m n}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
\vdots \\
x_m
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0(modz_1) \\
0(modz_2) \\
\vdots \\
0(modz_n)
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
Considering all numbers are in $\mathbb{Z}$, I know that the first equation given in the image must have a non-zero solution in $\mathbb{Z}$, such as taking the product of $z_1z_2\cdots z_n$. Essentially, this corresponds to whether the second equation has a solution, where $k_i$ can be any integer.
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{21} & \cdots & a_{m 1} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{m 2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{1 n} & a_{2 n} & \cdots & a_{m n}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
\vdots \\
x_m
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
k_1z_1 \\
k_2z_2 \\
\vdots \\
k_nz_n
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
However, on this basis, I also want to know if there are solutions with an odd sum (or, in other words, solutions with a 1-norm as odd). So, there is the third equation, where the coefficient matrix is augmented with a row of 1's, and the non-homogeneous term corresponds to an odd number. This corresponds to whether the first equation has a solution with an odd sum. I wonder if there are any friends who are familiar with this and could provide some guidance.
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
a_{11} & a_{21} & \cdots & a_{m 1} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{m 2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{1 n} & a_{2 n} & \cdots & a_{m n}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
\vdots \\
x_m
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 t_0+1 \\
k_1 z_1 \\
k_2 z_2 \\
\vdots \\
k_n z_n
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

The problem arises from my curiosity about what conditions a Cayley graph must satisfy to be a bipartite graph.

If the equations are in different rings, $\mathbb{Z}/z_i\mathbb{Z}$ here, I wouldn't put them in a matrix equation like you do in the first displayed equation.
The last equation can be written as $M, \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{b}$ with unknown $\mathbf{v}=(x_1,\dots,x_m,k_1,\dots,k_n)$ and now you simply have linear algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$. See chapter 2 in Cohen's "A course in computational algebraic number theory"

I hope you know when a circulant graph (a Cayley graph) over the finite cyclic group is bipartite. Similar generalizations can be had for Cayley graphs over dihedral groups and, with some more specifications, for Cayley graphs over nilpotent groups, as well as symmetric groups.

By the way, could you elaborate how bipartiteness of Cayley graphs correspond to your question?

See "On systems of linear diophantine equations" by Lazebnik (published in Mathematics Magazine).  Linear systems over the integers can be solved using the Smith normal form of the coefficient matrix.

Linear equations over integers are traditionally addressed in terms of lattices. E.g. see this introductory text: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rothvoss/lecturenotes/IntOpt-and-Lattices.pdf

@MaxAlekseyev,thank you for your response. I will carefully read the literature you provided.

@Josh,thank you for your response. I will carefully read the literature you provided.

@ChrisWuthrich,thank you for your response. Actually, I'm more interested in finding a simple criterion rather than an algorithm.

@vidyarthi.Actually, I'm considering the Cayley graph of an abelian group. To determine if it's bipartite, we only need to check if there exists an odd-length closed walk. Then, considering the generators and Cayley subsets of the corresponding abelian group, it corresponds to whether the first equation has an integer solution with an odd sum.

@vidyarthi,by the way,I did consider when the Cayley graph of a finite cyclic group is bipartite, but I haven't thought about what you mentioned later. Do you have any related resources you could share with me?thank you.
